# Mysqli login prepared statements

Tags: php, session, authentication, mysqli, prepare

Okay, I haved been maked a register system, but when I tried to make the login system it didn't work. When the user log in with the correct username and password its post "You are now logged in", but when I refresh the site, It says I need to login. And I has to ask how I could check the user is logged in exempel If the user logged in so echo this and if not so echo this..

Here is my code:

```
session_start();
            require 'inc/connect.php';

            if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])){
                if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
                    if(!empty($_POST['password'])){


                        $username = $_POST['name'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $user = $_SESSION['name'];

                        // KRYPTERING
                        $md5 = md5($password);
                        $sha1 = sha1($md5);
                        $crypt = crypt($sha1, 'st');
                        $md51 = md5($crypt);
                        $sha12 = sha1($md51);
                        $crypt1 = crypt($sha12, 'st');
                        $kode = base64_encode($crypt1);

                        $check = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=? && password=?");
                        $check->bind_param("ss", $username, $kode);
                        $check->execute();
                        $check->bind_result($username, $kode);
                        $print = $check->fetch();
                        $check->close();

                        if ($print)
                            echo "You are now logged in!";
                        else
                            echo "Username / Password was incorrect!";

                    } else
                        echo "You need something!";
                } else
                    echo "You need something!";
            }
```

Comment: Because you aren't setting anything in the session saying the login was successful, nor checking the same at the top of the page. (For instance, you can put username in the session when login is successful.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put the username in the session on successful login, to check for it at the top of the page, and redirect to a different when its already set.

```
session_start();
            require 'inc/connect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  //already logged in, redirect
  header('Location: otherpage.php');
  exit;
}

            if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])){
                if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
                    if(!empty($_POST['password'])){


                        $username = $_POST['name'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $user = $_SESSION['name'];

                        // KRYPTERING
                        $md5 = md5($password);
                        $sha1 = sha1($md5);
                        $crypt = crypt($sha1, 'st');
                        $md51 = md5($crypt);
                        $sha12 = sha1($md51);
                        $crypt1 = crypt($sha12, 'st');
                        $kode = base64_encode($crypt1);

                        $check = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=? && password=?");
                        $check->bind_param("ss", $username, $kode);
                        $check->execute();
                        $check->bind_result($username, $kode);
                        $print = $check->fetch();
                        $check->close();

                        if ($print)
                        {
                            //redirect to different page for the message
                            //echo "You are now logged in!";
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                             header('Location: otherpage.php');
                             exit;
                        }
                        else
                            echo "Username / Password was incorrect!";

                    } else
                        echo "You need something!";
                } else
                    echo "You need something!";
            }
```

Then in the other pages, you'll want something like:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  //not logged in, redirect to login form
  header('Location: login_form.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: And in the otherpage.php how do I check if he is logged in or not?

Comment: @HalaKeblawi Added that to the answer.

Comment: When I log ind, It can't go into otherpage.php it said could't not connect to the website, and the anothers page cannot connect, but when I delete the session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  //not logged in, redirect to login form
  header('Location: login_form.php');
  exit;
} I got connection to the website??

Comment: @HalaKeblawi Not sure I understand what you're saying, but obviously you have to change those names to names of files you actually have.